# How to draw this function with tikz $\frac12 \ln(\frac{x+1}{1-x})$?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My problem is it is defined on ]-1,1[ so I don't know how to write the domaine

```
\def\Xmin{-1} \def\Xmax{1} 
\def\Ymin{-2} \def\Ymax{2} 
\def\Xunit{1cm} \def\Yunit{1cm} 
\def\Xleg{\small \sffamily $x$} % légende en abscisse 
\def\Yleg{\small \sffamily $y$} % légende en ordonnées 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\Xunit,y=\Yunit] 
\draw[>= latex,->,thick](\Xmin,0)--(\Xmax,0); 
\draw[>= latex,->,thick](0,\Ymin)--(0,\Ymax); 
\draw [domain=\Xmin:0,thick,red] plot (\x,{((1/2) (ln((1+\x)/(1-\x)))) });
\draw [domain=0:\Xmax,thick,red] plot (\x,{((1/2) (ln((1+\x)/(1-\x)))) });
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i want to get something like this

[image]

Comment: You can use `\def\Xmin{-0.99} \def\Xmax{0.99} ` and then `\draw [domain=\Xmin:\Xmax,thick,red]`. But, like yesterday, it might be a better idea to use `pgfplots` for this.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution using `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin = -1.6,
        xmax = 1.6,
        > = Stealth
    ]
        \addplot[
            blue,
            thick,
            domain = -1:1,
            samples = 1000
        ]
            {0.5*ln((1+x)/(1-x))};
        \addplot[
            dashed,
            mark = none
        ]
            coordinates {(-1,-4) (-1,4)};
        \addplot[
            dashed,
            mark = none
        ]
            coordinates {(1,-4) (1,4)};
        \addplot[
            <->,
            thick,
            mark = none
        ]
            coordinates {(-1.1,-1.1) (1.1,1.1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots-sample]

Answer (score 6):

Function `y = 1/2 * ln((x + 1) / (x - 1))` approaches to infinity when x approaches to 1 or -1. Moreover, this function is **undefined** at both x = 1 and x = -1. Hence, you can only plot this function in the range `(-1 + delta, 1 - delta)`, where `delta` is a small positive value. Therefore,

- The plot domain is changed to `[-1 + \Xshift, 1 - \Xshift]` where `\Xshift` is a small positive number.
- To imitate the drawing range, y-range is changed to `[-3, 3]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\Xmin{-1} \def\Xmax{1} 
\def\Ymin{-3} \def\Ymax{3} 
\def\Xunit{1cm} \def\Yunit{1cm} 
\def\Xleg{\small \sffamily $x$} % légende en abscisse 
\def\Yleg{\small \sffamily $y$} % légende en ordonnées 

\def\Xshift{0.005} % \Xshift is not a good name, :(

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\Xunit,y=\Yunit]
  \draw[>= latex,->,thick] (\Xmin-.5, 0) -- (\Xmax+.5, 0); 
  \draw[>= latex,->,thick] (0, \Ymin)   -- (0, \Ymax);

  \draw [domain=\Xmin+\Xshift:\Xmax-\Xshift, samples=700, very thick, red] 
    plot (\x, {0.5*(ln((1+\x)/(1-\x)))});

  \draw[dashed] (\Xmin, \Ymin) -- (\Xmin, \Ymax);
  \draw[dashed] (\Xmax, \Ymin) -- (\Xmax, \Ymax);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: draw by tikz]

Comment: it is not like the picture the axes are small then the graph how to ameliorate this please ?

Comment: Maybe add `\draw [domain=\Xmin+0.1:0,thick,red] plot (\x,{((1/2) (ln((1+\x)/(1-\x)))) });` just before the plots.

Comment: what is Xshift ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali See the updated answer.

Comment: Please how to draw x=1 and x=-1 ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali updated again. BTW @Zarko's `pgfplots` solution is more complete and elegant.

Answer (score 5):

Another `pgfplots` solution:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
            x=1cm, y=1cm,      % global defined image features, instead "\def"
            ticklabel style={rounded corners=4pt, fill=white, inner xsep=1pt,
                             font=\small\sffamily},
            xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5, 
            ymin=-3.5,ymax=3.5, 
            set layers = axis on top,
             }


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
xtick=\empty, extra x ticks={-1,0,1},
ytick=\empty,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
samples at ={-1,-0.998,...,-0.5,-0.4,...,0.5,0.5002,0.5004,...,1}
             ]
\addplot [blue, very thick]  {0.5*(ln((1+x)/(1-x)))};
%
\addplot [dashed] coordinates {(-1,-3.5) (-1,3.5) };
\addplot [dashed] coordinates {( 1,-3.5) ( 1,3.5) };
%
\draw[<->,semithick]  (-1.5,-1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) node[above, pos=0.1, sloped] {$\Delta$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please @Zarko if I want to draw a function defined on $]-\infty,-1[\cup]1,+\infty[$ how to change ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali, well form `-\infty` to  `+\infty`, is not possible, you need infinity wide paper ;-). Seriously, are you sure, that your function exist outside domain  `-1:1` ?

Comment: no @zarko not this function, an other one $\frac12\ln(\frac{x+1}{x-1})$

Comment: @lindaOiladali, but diagram show this function! In principle it is possible, if function exist. You only need accordingly to change in my answer to given function optimizet secting samplin points with for example `\domain=-10:10, samples=2001` and change `\xmin` and `\xmyx` accordingly. However, about this would be better to ask new question for your new particular case and consider, that this your question is answered. So you only need to accept (by clicking on check mark at top left side of selected answer) from gotten answers the one, which you the most liked :-)